# Is this the correct way to set up a decision tree in java?

Tags: java

I need to create a decision tree using 'ifs' 'elses' and 'if else' if required.
i tried using only ifs but i couldn't get it to work properly. I've redone the beginning part using elses as well as ifs. I am getting an error that 'answer1' is not found. Can someone tell me if this is the correct start? I don't want to code the whole thing again and have to redo a lot of it because the results are not right.

Ive used only if statements but im thinking i have to use elses as well. if i were to include everything I've tried it would be well over 200 lines so ill keep it to this revised part I've started on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Guessing {
public static void main(String[]args) {

```
Scanner guess = new Scanner( System.in );
System.out.println("Think of something");
System.out.println("is it a living animal, plant, or non-living thing?");

String answer0;
answer0 = guess.nextLine();
answer0 = answer0.toUpperCase();
switch (answer0) 
{
   case "PLANT"   :  System.out.println("Is it a tree?"); 
      break;
  // case "LIVING :  System.out.println("Does it have feathers, fur, or neither"); break;
  // case "NON-LIVING" :   System.out.println("Is it man-made?"); break;
  // case "NON LIVING" :   System.out.println("Is it man-made?");
      default    :   System.out.println("Invalid"); 
}

   if (answer0.equals("PLANT")) 
{
   System.out.println("Is it deciduous?");
   String = answer1;
   answer1 = guess.nextLine();
   answer1 = answer1.toUpperCase();
   switch (answer1) 
   {
   case "YES"  :  System.out.println("Is it a fruit tree?");
      break;
   case "NO"   :  System.out.println("Is it native to North America?");
      break;
   default     :  System.out.println("Invalid");
   }
}
   if  (answer1.equals("NO"))
{
   System.out.println("Does it have an enclosed seed?");
   String answerq3;
   answerq3 = guess.nextLine();
   answerq3 = answerq3.toUpperCase();
   switch (answerq3) 
   {
      case "YES"  :  System.out.println("Are you thinking of a cypress tree?");
         break;
      case "NO"   :  System.out.println("Are you thinking of a yew?");
         break;
      default     :  System.out.println("Invalid");
   }
   String answer4;
   answer4 = guess.nextLine(); 
   answer4 = answer4.toUpperCase();
   switch (answer4) 
   {
      case "YES"  :  System.out.println("Correct"); 
         break;
      case "NO"   :  System.out.println("Wrong");   
         break;
      default     :  System.out.println("Invalid"); 
   }
}
    //  if answer = tangerine tree 
    //     system.out.print("Correct");
//}








  //    else {
  //    System.out.println("is it a banana tree");
      //}
   else
   {
   System.out.println("is it a weeping tree?");
   }

else
{
System.out.println("Does it have flowers?");
}


 }
 }
```

its kind of hard to describe the expected results of a decision tree without going on and on and it getting confusing or being able to post a picture

Comment: With respect to the compiler error - you correctly declare an answer*N* three out of four times. Look at the odd one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you're on the right track. If yes, this is what I ask next, if no ask some thing else. And you continue this again and again. If I understood you code correctly it looks good. So `if` yes, and than `else if` no, and `else` input is invalid. Try that, and Good Luck!

Comment: i have fixed the minor compiler error as pointed out by another-dave but it's giving me an "error: else without if". I've checked by brackets multiple times but I'm not sure what could be causing it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: `else without if` is caused when you say have if statement and say you tried to but and else statement with it but instead you put it inside the if statement. If you have correct indentation it will be easier to find. Can you edit your question with your current code and then comment back so I can look at what you currently have?

Comment: I'm still kind of new to coding so I'm not sure if this is this is exactly the right indentation but just let me know so I can fix it. (i didn't bother with the comments)

Comment: I think the case statements are redundant, a case statement is for multiple options, you only have three, YES, NO, and invalid. So use `if`, `else if`, and `else` respectively. That will help you orignize it better.

Comment: I've recoded it to use ifs else-ifs and elses but I'm still getting the "else without if" error on a couple lines. Since the code is pretty different I'm probably gonna make a new post on it or see if it is already answered somewhere